# Setting transparent images background in IrfanView

Tags: image, transparency, alpha, irfanview

I have some PNG images which consist of a black shape and a transparent background.
Unfortunately, IrfanView shows transparent background as black color, so I see just black on black. I've found in Irfan settings that I can change the window's background color, but it changes only around the image, the transparent color is still black.

Is there any way to change the color displayed as transparent, or, optimally, use white-grey squares like Photoshop?

Comment: To note: `Options` > `Properties` > `Viewing` > `Main window color`.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You were on the right track. IrfanView sets the background for transparency the same as the viewing color around the image.

You just need to re-open the image with IrfanView after changing the view color to white.

To change the viewing color in Irfanview go to:

```
Options > Properties/Settings > Viewing > Main window color
```

Comment: How to change the viewing color: Options > Properties/Settings > Viewing > Main window color

Comment: Does not work for me. Paste transparent image into white window -> window turns black.

Comment: Make sure 'Show PNG/TIF/TGA/DDS alpha/transparent color' is ticked on the same settings section.

Comment: It works for saved files but does not work when a picture is copy & pasted from the clipboard. For example, picture shown in a browser  -> right click to copy image... -> open irfan -> paste. That results in black background. But I'm not sure whether it's irfan issue or the clipboard stores data w/o transparency information.

Comment: @tom The key step is **re-open the image ... after changing the view color to white**. Seems like a bug in irfanview that you have to re-open it, but anyway this works.

Comment: ha, ha, ha, great, thanks! :) I wish IrfanView could automatically do that.

Comment: I had to first open the PNG with Paint. Or maybe the install was still getting registered in the background in Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Wow. I consider the reopening thing quite a bug as well, very annoying.

Comment: This still doesn't work, if the image is all white; with "Show transparent color" enabled, and the main window color set to white, now all you see is a white square.  Or am i missing something?

Comment: My Irfanview is configured to open in Full Screen Mode: the background is black in any case and the transparent colour black too; if I exit full screen (ESC) it remains black. If I remove the option to start in Full Screen Mode, everything is fine. Sort of a bug, I guess.

Comment: Years later Google search found your directions on how to correct this annoying problem!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the batch conversion, in the window click "options" in the "Batch conversion settings-output format" and tick the two boxes "save transparent color" (one under "PNG" and the other under "ICO").

Comment: Based on my tests, this actually seems to be the easiest and most effective solution to saved icons missing transparency. Just make sure you click "options" like @Annalisa says, and not "Advanced"

Comment: I don't think this answer the question. The question is about displaying transparency in IrfanView, not about saving transparent images.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced > Canvas Size 'Settings' > canvas color: 'OK'

I've read all of these and eventually figured out my resolution.

The images have worked for me on this occasion and saved me several hours.